# Issue starting a Ruby on Rails application in production mode on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localhost, production-environment

I am using Ruby on Rails and I am working on *localhost* with *multiple* applications.

Since I am using Apache, I tryed to set Virual Hosts like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName <application_name>
  DocumentRoot "/<directory_name>/public"

  #RackEnv development
  RackEnv production

  <Directory "/<directory_name>/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I run `echo $RAILS_ENV` in the Terminal (I use a Mac OS) I get `production`, but when I try to `rake db:create` I get

```
(in /<directory_name>)
<application_name>_test already exists
<application_name>_development already exists
```

That means *I can't create the production database*.

**So, how to solve that issue? How run my applications in production mode?**

Of course, if I go to the browser in order to navigate my application, I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error
Unknown database '<application_name>_production'
```

*P.S.*: I have Webrick.

Comment: What do you see if you try explicitly setting the environment like this: `rake db:create environment RAILS_ENV=production`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```